# Is there a way to square off line margins in histogram plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, formatting, histogram, bar-chart

I made a histogram plot in R using `plot(type = 'h')`.

```
plot(type='h', y =runif(1:10), x = 1:10,lwd = 20,lty=7)
```

I want the vertical bars to be thick, so I increase `lwd`. 
However, the larger "bars" (really, they're *lines*) have rounded edges:

[image]

**Is there a way to make these "bars" (i.e., lines) have square/straight edges?**

I've gone through the [plot documentation](http://127.0.0.1:10555/library/graphics/html/plot.html) numerous times and couldn't find a solution. No SE or Google Searches turned up anything either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lend = 1`.

```
plot(type='h', y =runif(1:10), x = 1:10,lwd = 20,l ty = 7, lend = 1)
```

And output

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for cluing me into this! Works perfectly!!